# Databricks SQL Editor "Failure to initialize configuration"

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I'm trying to select something from one specific table in SQL Editor, I'm getting an error "Failure to initialize configuration".
The query is simple as `select * from table_name`. Tried also with limits and/or selecting specific columns, but got the same error.

If I switch to "Data Science & Engineering" and execute the same query using a regular cluster in a notebook everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the Spark Config by entering the connection information for your Azure Storage account.
This will allow your cluster to access the files. Enter the following:

spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net <ACCESS_KEY>, where <STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME> is your Azure Storage account name, and <ACCESS_KEY> is your storage access key.

If using Azure Key vault, you can create a KeyVault backed secret scope (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes) and access the values via the following syntax in your spark config: {{secrets//}}

Comment: How exactly can we edit Spark Config?